# facing issue with gradle git zoltu plugin?

Tags: git, gradle

I am using below plugin for managing the patch version automatically.

```
id "com.zoltu.git-versioning" version "3.0.3"
```

Basically the above plugin requires code to be taged using v.major.minor convention.
So, I have tagged the code with v0.1 and the tag is reachable form the HEAD.

But still I am getting below error -

> - What went wrong: A problem occurred evaluating root project 'report-service'.
>
> > Your repository must have at least one tag in it for git-versioning to work.  Recommended solution: git tag v0.0

and `git tag` shows there is a tag and i have checked the revision history and this tag is reachable from the branch I am working on -

```
$ git tag
v0.1
```

Does anyone have any clue what the issue is. This a blocker for me.
Thanks in advance for any help..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This actually comes from [`Zoltu/Gradle.Plugin.Versioning` `kotlin/com/zoltu/gradle/plugin/GitVersioning.kt`](https://github.com/Zoltu/Gradle.Plugin.Versioning/blob/master/src/main/kotlin/com/zoltu/gradle/plugin/GitVersioning.kt#L61-L69)

```
    private fun getGitDescribeResults(rootDirectory: File): String {
        val repository = FileRepositoryBuilder()
                .findGitDir(rootDirectory)!!
                .apply { gitDir ?: throw Exception("Project must be in a git directory for git-versioning to work.  Recommended solution: git init") }
                .build()!!
        val git = Git.wrap(repository)!!
        if (git.repository.allRefs.count() == 0) throw Exception("Your repository must have at least one commit in the repository for git-versioning to work.  Recommended solution: git commit")
        return git.describe().setLong(true).call() ?: throw Exception("Your repository must have at least one tag in it for git-versioning to work.  Recommended solution: git tag v0.0")
    }
```

As noted by [torek](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1256452/torek) in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73538054/facing-issue-with-gradle-git-zoltu-plugin/73538646?noredirect=1#comment129862117_73538646), check if your [tag is lightweight or annotated](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40480534/6309).
[`git describe`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-describe) would [by default ignore lightweight tags](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4154518/6309).

---

In [`Zoltu/Gradle.Plugin.Versioning` issue 25](https://github.com/Zoltu/Gradle.Plugin.Versioning/issues/25), [Micah Zoltu](https://github.com/MicahZoltu) (maintainer for that plugin) mentions having:

- [updated the documentation](https://github.com/Zoltu/Gradle.Plugin.Versioning/pull/26/files)
- Identified a possible fix in [`src/main/kotlin/com/zoltu/gradle/plugin/GitVersioning.kt`](https://github.com/Zoltu/Gradle.Plugin.Versioning/blob/20fee206a2c8a2fdeac10dcb290e0543dca7a5ad/src/main/kotlin/com/zoltu/gradle/plugin/GitVersioning.kt#L68) to allow using lightweight tags
- [Implemented it](https://github.com/Zoltu/Gradle.Plugin.Versioning/pull/27), but it needs JGit 6.X and a more recent version of Java, and the GitHub publishing workflow is broken.

Comment: Hard to know without diving into the details of `git.describe()` in Kotlin here, but perhaps the tag must be an *annotated* tag as well?

Comment: @torek Good point, thank you. I have edited the answer to make that possible cause more visible.

Comment: annotated tags helped +1

Comment: @torek / VonC - would you mind taking a look at this too: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73541172/com-gorylenko-generategitpropertiestask-property-gitproperties-is-missing-an any help is very much appreciated.